# Error: Expected no open requests, found 1

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am getting this error when I try to execute HTTP unit test cases.

I am using Angular 5. How can I resolve this?

Below is my code for normal GET. Below code just brings normal GET.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController, TestRequest } from 
'@angular/common/http/testing';

import { DangerService } from './danger.service';
import { DangerFlag } from '../danger.model';


describe('DataService Tests', () => {
    let dataService: DangerService;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

    let testDangerFlags: DangerFlag[] = [ "sample data" ]

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
        providers: [ DangerService ]
    });

    dataService = TestBed.get(DangerService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
});

afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
});

fit('should get all danger flags', () => {
    dataService.getDangerFlagDetails()
        .subscribe((data: DangerFlag[]) => {
            expect(data.length).toBe(3);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's better to put the error messages inline, rather than in a title, so it can be treated like copyable text easier. Also, there are lots of ways to debug Angular apps that can probably be applied to test execution. A web search showed lots of those, as well as many refs to this error message. What other research have you done?

Comment: actually i am new to angular.. When i try to write expect none as a Unit test it works.. But logically it is not correct

Answer (score 23):

> Expected no open requests, found 1

This happens when you make a mock request, but don't 'complete/close' it. An open request may stay open after a test is run, eventually memory leaking, especially if the test is ran multiple times.

Subscribing to a mock request **calls it as far as the client side is concerned** but does not 'complete' it as far as the backend is concerned. 'Completing' a request can be done in a number of ways;

`backend = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController)`

1. `backend.expectOne(URL)` - this will both test for a url, and 'close' the backend call. This will not test for params, and will fail if your query has params in it.
2. `backend.expectNone(URL)` - in case you're testing for urls that have params, `expectOne()` wont work. You'll have to use `backend.match()`. Match does not auto close the backend api call, so you can `expectNone()` after it to close it out.
3. `.flush(RESPONSE)` - flush will force-send a response for the http call, and subsequently close the call. Note: if calling flush on a `match()`, watch out for match returning an array, i.e. `backend.match(...)[0].flush({})`

Any of these methods will close out the http request, and make `backend.verify()` behave.

#### References

- You can find in depth examples, and more explanations [here](https://www.ng-conf.org/2019/angulars-httpclient-testing-depth/)
- `expectOne()` and `match()` return an instance of [TestRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/TestRequest)
- `expectNone()` always returns `void`

Comment: In-depth examples link is dead. One complete example of a test would be nice to have inside the answer.

Comment: What I need to use if the request have parameters instead of backend.expectOne(URL)?

Comment: Here is the new [link](https://2019.ng-conf.org/angulars-httpclient-testing-depth/)

Answer (score 6):

I also faced this issue today. Add **expectOne** function call

```
it('should get all danger flags', () => {
   const actualDangerFlags = createDangerFlagResponse();
   dataService.getDangerFlagDetails()
       .subscribe((actualDangerFlags) => {
        expect(data.length).toBe(3);
     });
   });

   const httpRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(BASE_URL + relativeURL);
   expect(httpRequest.request.method).toBe('GET');
   httpRequest.flush(actualDangerFlags);
});

createDangerFlagResponse(): DangerFlag[] {
    return /* DangerFlag Array */
}
```

Comment: It appears that the httpTestingController matchers are buggy! @Ronnie your suggestion worked for me when I faced similar issue using expectOne({url: 'xyz', method 'POST'}) matcher

Answer (score 4):

If a test is async, you have to tell jasmine that it is async and when it is finished.

```
it('should get all danger flags', (done) =>{^
                                   ^^^^^^
    dataService.getDangerFlagDetails()
         .subscribe((data: DangerFlag[]) =>{
              expect(data.length).toBe(3);
              done();
              ^^^^^^
         });
});
```

You do that by calling a function that jasmine will provide when running a test as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Add **expectOne** function call, if it doesn't solve then try below might be helping you

Sometimes the validation part might be going wrong, please add an alert or a console to verify the true condition in my case it happened,

```
          service.authenticate(model).subscribe(token => {
                expect(token).toBeTruthy();
                expect(token).toBeDefined();
            });
            const request = httpTestingController.expectOne(req =>{
              console.log("url: ", request.url);
              return  req.method === 'GET' && req.url === URL
            });
            expect(request.request.method).toBe('GET');
            request.flush(response);
```

Hope it will solve problem :)

Happy Coding !!!